# Equivalence between the fictitious magnetic charges and surface current

Tags: electromagnetism

In my electromagnetics textbook. There is an example that jf a sphere with radius $R$ is uniformly magnetized by $\textbf{M}=M\hat{\textbf{z}}$, we can get the magnetic field by regarding it either produced by a surface density of fictitious magnetic charge $\sigma_M=\textbf{M}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}}$ or by a surface density of magnetization current $\textbf{K}=\textbf{M}\times\textbf{n}$.

Since these two pictures are equivalent in getting the correct magnetic field. The dipole moment they produce must be the same outside the sphere, right? If we use the relation $\textbf{m}=V\textbf{M}$, we get $$\textbf{m}=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}\textbf{M}$$
However, if we calculate the dipole moment directly from the current $\textbf{K}$, we get
$$\textbf{m}=\frac{1}{2}\int d^3r\ \textbf{r}\times \textbf{j}(\textbf{r})
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{r=R} dS\ \textbf{r}\times \textbf{K}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} \int_{r=R}dS\ \textbf{r}\times(\textbf{M}\times\hat{\textbf{n}})$$

In order to evaluate this integral, we use the following vector identity
$$\textbf{a}\times(\textbf{b}\times\textbf{c})=(\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{c})\textbf{b}-(\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b})\textbf{c}$$
to get
$$\int_{r=R}dS\ \textbf{r}\times(\textbf{B}_0\times\hat{\textbf{n}})=\int_{r=R}dS\ ((\textbf{r}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}})\textbf{M}-(\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{M})\hat{\textbf{n}})$$
Notice that due to symmetry, the $(\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{M})\hat{\textbf{n}}$ doesn't contribute to the integral, so we are left with $$\int_{r=R}dS\ (\textbf{r}\cdot\hat{\textbf{n}})\textbf{M}=4\pi R^3 \textbf{M}$$
Therefore, we have
$$\textbf{m}=2\pi R^3\textbf{M}$$
Why is the dipole moment different if the two representations are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second term $(\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf M) \hat{\mathbf n}$ is a vector, and it does contribute to the integral.

Let us orient the cartesian coordinate system so that $\mathbf M$ points in direction of the $z$ axis.

Then we have

$$
(\mathbf r\cdot \mathbf M) \hat{\mathbf n} = M R~ n_z (n_x,n_y,n_z).
$$

Third component of this vector is always positive or zero (at the equator of the sphere), so its surface integral over the sphere can't be zero.